# Change list's bind value on change of first bind value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a View Model with properties as below. Two are a normal integers and third is a list of another View Model. In constructor I create ObservableCollection IterationVMList

```
    private IterationVM CurrentIterationVM;
    public ObservableCollection<IterationVM> IterationVMList { get; set; }

    private int numberOfIterations
    public int NumberOfIterations
    {
        get
        {

            return numberOfIterations
        }
        set
        {
            if numberOfIterations!= value)
            {
                numberOfIterations= value;
                while (IterationVMList.Count() < value)
                {
                    IterationVM It = new IterationVM();
                    IterationVMList.Add(It);
                }
                CurrentIterationVM = IterationVMList[numberOfIterations - 1];
                OnPropertyChanged("NumberOfIterations");
                OnPropertyChanged("Seed");

            }
        }
    }

    public int Seed
    {
        get
        {
            return CurrentIterationVM.Seed;
        }
        set
        {
            if (CurrentIterationVM.Seed != value)
            {
                CurrentIterationVM.Seed = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Seed");
            }
        }
    }
```

In xaml what I want is that when the user changes NumberOfIterations, it should change the seed. How do I do that without calling OnPropertyChanged("Seed") in NumberOfIterations property. Is there a better way to do this?

```
<xceed:IntegerUpDown Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Width="100" Margin="5" Text="{Binding NumberOfIterations,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Minimum="1"/>
<xceed:IntegerUpDown Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Width="100" Margin="5" Text="{Binding Seed, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Minimum="1"/>
```

Comment: Make the CurrentIterationVM Public RaisePropery and Bind to its Seed Property.

Comment: suggestion: don't use Linq extension method `Count()` when there is `Count` property. just `IterationVMList.Count < value`, not `IterationVMList.Count() < value`

Comment: Thanks that works. I will also change the IterationVMList.Count from IterationVMList.Count()